# How to create decision variables in R for linear programming?

Tags: python, r, mathematical-optimization, pulp, lpsolve

How should i create a list of n variables indexed by nth index(string - key) 
For example
X['one'] should be treated as decision variable with index value 'one'.

After creating the decision variable -

Assuming there are two decision variables X(list indexed) & Y(list indexed), How should I refer to the variables such as X['one'] + Y['two'] >= 1

I am interested in an approach that is closely similar to pulp package in python for creating variables and constraints using those variables

Answer (score 0):

I do not know PULP, but I guess [ompr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ompr/index.html) or [CVXR](https://cvxr.rbind.io/index.html) might be worth a try.